# Boolean filtering using AND - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, boolean

I just can't seem to get the proper output when filtering the `df` below using boolean operators. I want the `df` to remove rows where `ID` is `<= 2` AND `String` `== A,B, or C`. Is seems to be removing strings that are not equal to `A,B, or C`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'String' : ['A','F','B','C','D','A','X','C','B','D','A','Y','A','C','A','D','C','B'],                  
    'ID' : [4,2,3,4,5,6,4,2,3,4,5,6,4,2,3,4,5,6], 
        })

df = df[~(df['ID'] <= 2) & (df['String'].isin(['A','B','C']))]
```

intended Output:

```
   String  ID
0       A   4
1       F   2
2       B   3
3       C   4
4       D   5
5       A   6
6       X   4
#7       C   2 Remove
8       B   3
9       D   4
10      A   5
11      Y   6
12      A   4
#13      C   2 Remove
14      A   3
15      D   4
16      C   5
17      B   6
```

Comment: you are missing a `~` in front of the second term

Comment: `df = df[~((df['ID'] <= 2) & (df['String'].isin(['A','B','C'])))]
`

Comment: OR : `df = df[df['ID'].le(2) | df['String'].isin(['A','B','C'])]`